# Prevent adding duplicate items on ListView

Tags: c#, linq

Could someone give me LINQ code to avoid allowing duplicate items when adding new items into `ListView`?

Here's my current code for adding items from clipboard with regex.

```
List<string> uri = new List<string>();
string URLPattern = cbRegEx.Text;
string cb = Clipboard.GetText();

uri.Clear();
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(cb, URLPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    uri.Add(m.Value);
}

LV_Url.BeginUpdate();
foreach (var Uri in uri)
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
    lv.Text = (LV_Url.Items.Count + 1).ToString();
    lv.SubItems.Add(GetUrlFileName(Uri));
    lv.SubItems.Add(Uri);
    LV_Url.Items.Add(lv);
    LV_Url.AutoResizeColumn(1, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
}
LV_Url.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a distinct string collection from the Clipboard and insert the items into a ListView *except* the duplicates:

```cs
var urls = new List<string>();
//...
//get them from the Clipboard...
//...

//Add the new Urls only:
LV_Url.BeginUpdate();

LV_Url.Items.AddRange(
    urls
    .Distinct()
    .Where(url => LV_Url.Items.Count == 0 
    || LV_Url.FindItemWithText(url, true, 0) == null)
    .Select((url, i) => new ListViewItem(new[]
    {
        (LV_Url.Items.Count + i + 1).ToString(),
        GetUrlFileName(url),
        url
    }
    )).ToArray());

//Optional to fit the contents...
LV_Url.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.Width = -2);
LV_Url.EndUpdate();
```

Or add from the Clipboard directly:

```cs
LV_Url.BeginUpdate();

LV_Url.Items.AddRange(
    Regex.Matches(Clipboard.GetText(),
    URLPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value) //Or some m.Groups[n].Value...
    .Distinct()
    .Where(url => LV_Url.Items.Count == 0 
    || LV_Url.FindItemWithText(url, true, 0) == null)
    .Select((url, i) => new ListViewItem(new[]
    {
        (LV_Url.Items.Count + i + 1).ToString(),
        GetUrlFileName(url),
        url
    }
    )).ToArray());

LV_Url.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.Width = -2);
LV_Url.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: I tried this but this is the error: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'startIndex'.

Comment: @zackmark15 Yes, you'll get this when the ListView is emptry. I'l Fix it.

Comment: Yes if I have question again :) I'm just learning with my own and I'm creating my personal  tools

Answer (score 4):

Use `HashSet<string>` instead of using `List<string>`, it's going to ignore  allowing duplicate value in the list.

```
HashSet<string> list = new HashSet<string>();
list.Add("duplicate");
list.Add("duplicate");
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);//output 1
```

Comment: If you want `HashSet<string>` being **case-insensitive** use this constructor: `new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Distinct()` to remove dublicates

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(cb, URLPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in mc.Distinct())
{
    uri.Add(m.Value);
}
```

Or

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(cb, URLPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    uri.Add(m.Value);
}
uri = uri.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally thanks for all your answer. But this is what I used :)
Thanks to @JQSOFT

```
        LV_Url.BeginUpdate();
        LV_Url.Items.AddRange(Regex.Matches(Clipboard.GetText(), URLPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline)
            .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
            .Where(url => LV_Url.Items.Count == 0 || LV_Url.FindItemWithText(url, true, 0) == null)
            .Select((url, i) => new ListViewItem(new[]
            {
                (LV_Url.Items.Count + i + 1).ToString(),
                Util.GetUrlFileName(url),
                url

            })).ToArray());
        LV_Url.EndUpdate();
```